# RIGHT statement nested within an IF statement with multiple logic statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column in a dataset which contains rows of 17 digit product IDs. The first 8 Digits correspond to a product type (A, B, C, D). I am trying to create a new column that will contain the corresponding product based on the first 8 digits.

If 85161007 = Product A, 85677007 = Product B and 85648007 = Product C, how can I write a nested IF statement that can filter through the entire column and output the product type on the new column?

```
Product ID              
851610070000003256
856770070000003254
856480070000003896
```

Comment: Use a lookup table and look up the left 8 digits.

Comment: Which would mean you would use `LEFT` (or `MID`) instead of `RIGHT` as your title suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BigBen said, you have to create a lookup table where all the products and their codes will be located, then you can find the name you need with a simple formula:

if id is text:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$4,MATCH(LEFT(A2,8),$F$2:$F$4,0),0)
```

or if id is number:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$4,MATCH(LEFT(A2,8)+0,$F$2:$F$4,0),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to achieve this.
But if we stick to the question:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,8)="85161007","PRODUCT A",IF(LEFT(A1,8)="85677007",
                "PRODUCT B",IF(LEFT(A9,1)="85648007","PRODUCT C","ELSE")))
```

Note that, in this case I compare strings. If your data is formatted as numbers, you will want to compare numbers (which means removing quotation marks (") on each sides of these ID in the formula.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I'm still learning excel so did not know much about VLOOKUP. I guess it is the more easier method to use. Thanks for the answer though